# How do I model many-to-many relationships with tables that have similar attributes?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, many-to-many, database-schema

Here's a fairly straightforward many-to-many mapping of Nerf gun toys to the price range that they fall under.  The Zombie Strike and Elite Retaliator are pricey, while both the Jolt Blaster and Elite Triad are cheaper (in the $5.00-$9.99) range.

[image]

[image]

So far so good.  But what happens when I want to start tracking the prices of other items?  These other items have different columns, but still need PRICE_RANGES mappings.  So I can potentially still use the PRICE_RANGES table, but I need other tables for the other items.

Let's add board games.  How should I model this new table, and others like it?

Should I add multiple many-to-many tables, one for each new type of item I'm tracking?

[image]

Or should I denormalize PRICE_RANGES, get rid of the mapping tables altogether, and just duplicate PRICE_RANGES tables for every item type?

[image]

The second solution has the advantage of being much similar, but at the cost of duplicating all the ranges in PRICE_RANGES.  (and there may be many thousands of PRICE_RANGES, depending on how small the increments are).  Is that denormalization still a valid solution?

Or maybe there's a third way that's considered better than these two?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: My first suggestion would be the same as @ben-sala's answer, where you have a common Product table and then a ProductType column. Seeing as you don't wish this solution, i'm going to have to go with the first solution. The only time i would use the second solution, is if the price ranges are different for each kind of product. Normalization is USUALLY the way to go no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a "price ranges" table at all?  That would make it highly restrictive.  Unless there is a really compelling reason I am missing... Here is what I would consider.

- Drop the mapping tables
- Drop the price ranges tables
- Add a min price and max price to each table you want to track price ranges.  If there is no range, you can either allow max price to be null, or make both be the same price. Then you can just query the tables to find items within whatever range you want.

Another thought I would consider... how many different types of products are you trying to track?  If you are going to make a separate table for every single kind of product... that will quickly become unmanageable if you expect to have hundreds or thousands of items.  Consider having a "Product" table that has columns that share attributes, such as price, across all the products.  It would have a ProductType column that either references a lookup table or just puts the types directly in the column.  Then have either a separate key/value table to cover other random things like bolt capacity.  Or even consider putting that in an xml/json/blob column to cover all the extra bits of info.

Comment: Ben, thanks for your comments.  What I didn't make clear is how this is a many-to-many relationship.  Not only can prices ranges be shared by many different products; a product can actually have many price ranges.  (For example, an item may fall into both the $5.00-$9.99 and the $10.00-$14.99 category, for various reasons).  That's why the many-to-many table is needed in the middle.  Otherwise yes, a simpler solution would have solved the problem. Regarding your 2nd question, there actually won't be many product types - maybe 10-20.  So I didn't consider it too hard to make a table for each.

Comment: Why then wouldn't you just put min price at $5 and max price at $14.99 for the given item ?